# How do I tell who is connected to my network and how much bandwidth they're using?

Tags: networking, wifi, monitoring

My router died today, so I used nm-applet on xfce to make a wireless network using my computer and modem. It only appeared to support WEP security. I felt I should keep track of who is connected, but I couldn't find out how, and Google only came up with results for iPhones and Android. How could I tell who's connected and how much bandwidth they're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A GUI program I personally like is [EtherApe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherApe), which has a nice graph showing current network activity with protocol and traffic amount.